# Eigenvalue of 2D discrete Laplacian

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying to solve for the eigenvalue of the discretized Laplacian

$$\Delta u \approx Mu=f$$

with $u(t,x)\in \mathbb{R}^{1 \times 2}$ and $\partial D=0 \quad \forall x\in \partial D$.
The grid $D$ is rectangular with $n$ horizontal and $m$ vertical inner gridpoints.

The matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{mn \times mn}$ is your ordinary five point stencil and can be represented by

$$M=\begin{Bmatrix}
B & -I &  &\\
-I & B & -I &\\
&... & ... & ... & \\
& & & -I &B
\end{Bmatrix}$$

with

$$B_n=\begin{Bmatrix}
4 &-1 &  &\\
-1 & 4 & -1 &\\
&... & ... & ... & \\
& & & -1 &4
\end{Bmatrix}
=\begin{Bmatrix}
a &b &  &\\
b & a & b &\\
&... & ... & ... & \\
& & & b &a
\end{Bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$$

and $I$ being your usual identity matrix.

Using Laplace expansion to calulate the determinant of $A=M-\lambda I$ (always first column downwards) leads me to the following recurrence relation:

$$\lvert A_{n} \rvert=\lvert B_{n} \rvert,$$
$$\lvert A_{k} \rvert=(4-\lambda+(-1)^n)\lvert A_{k-1} \rvert-(1+(-1)^{n-1})\lvert A_{k-2} \rvert$$

In theory, because I am able to derive an expression for the first equation via Chebyshev polynomials, I would also be able to solve the second equation for even $n$ (because then $\lvert A_{k-2} \rvert$ disappears).

But if I do it the result is nonsensical. I fear my current derivation of the recurrence relation might also be incorrect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If your goal is to compute the eigenvalues through this recurrence relation. The eigenvalues of tridiagonal block matrix is known, for example, please check https://mathoverflow.net/questions/210464/determinant-of-block-tridiagonal-matrices